# What is preventing my local storage JavaScript code from storing the data?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage

After closing the browser, the data is erased instead of stored. What is missing in my code?
Does local storage code need to be integrated into the rest of my pages code, or is it possible to have it all stored as coded below in a separate JS file?

```
function info(){
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        var sort = document.getElementById("sort").value;
        var newTask = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
        var taskDescr = document.getElementById("taskDescr").value;
        var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
        var category = document.getElementById("category").value;
        var importance = document.getElementById("importance").value;

        localStorage.sort = st;
        localStorage.newTask = nt;
        localStorage.taskDescr = td;
        localStorage.startDate = sd;
        localStorage.category = cg;
        localStorage.importance = im;

        document.getElementById("sort").value = localStorage.getItem("sort");
        document.getElementById("newTask").value = localStorage.getItem("newTask");
        document.getElementById("taskDescr").value = localStorage.getItem("taskDescr");
        document.getElementById("startDate").value = localStorage.getItem("startDate");
        document.getElementById("category").value = localStorage.getItem("category");
        document.getElementById("importance").value = localStorage.getItem("importance");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.sort+" "+localStorage.newTask+" "+localStorage.taskDescr+" "
        +localStorage.startDate+" "+localStorage.category+" "+localStorage.importance+" ";
        console.log("Result");
    }else{
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...");
    }
```

Comment: where are the variables `st, nt,td, sd, cg, im` comes from?

Comment: Sorry for my late response, yes it helps! Thanks so much for your time and clarifying the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firts thses variable is `st, nt,td, sd, cg, im` undefined You can use `localStorage.setItem('name', 'value');`. check the below code.

```
function info(){
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        var sort = document.getElementById("sort").value;
        var newTask = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
        var taskDescr = document.getElementById("taskDescr").value;
        var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
        var category = document.getElementById("category").value;
        var importance = document.getElementById("importance").value;

        localStorage.setItem('sort', sort);
        localStorage.setItem('newTask', newTask);
        localStorage.setItem('taskDescr', taskDescr);
        localStorage.setItem('startDate', startDate);
        localStorage.setItem('category', category);
        localStorage.setItem('importance', importance);

        document.getElementById("sort").value = localStorage.getItem("sort");
        document.getElementById("newTask").value = localStorage.getItem("newTask");
        document.getElementById("taskDescr").value = localStorage.getItem("taskDescr");
        document.getElementById("startDate").value = localStorage.getItem("startDate");
        document.getElementById("category").value = localStorage.getItem("category");
        document.getElementById("importance").value = localStorage.getItem("importance");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.sort+" "+localStorage.newTask+" "+localStorage.taskDescr+" "
        +localStorage.startDate+" "+localStorage.category+" "+localStorage.importance+" ";
        console.log("Result");
    }else{
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...");
    }
}
```